# Carregar lista a partir de txt em c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, arraylist

Tenho o seguinte problema, eu pego os dados de um txt que eu preciso devolver em forma de `List<List<string>>`, porém eu só consigo pegar do txt um  `string [] linha`, então eu estava adicionando string por string no meu list, isso funciona, porém a cada vez que é adicionado o novo list, os mesmos valores são adicionados mais uma vez no mesmo list, segue o código.

```
   public List<List<string>> carregaHistoria( string nomeHistoria ){

      List<List<string>> historia = new List<List<string>> () {} ;

      List<string> listaIntermediaria = new List<string>(){};

      FileInfo theSourceFile =
            new FileInfo ( Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + nomeHistoria + ".txt");

      StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();

      string text;

      string [] linha;

      do
      {
         linha = reader.ReadLine().Split('|');

         text = reader.ReadLine();

         for(int j = 0; j < linha.Length ; j++){

            listaIntermediaria.Add(linha[j]) ;
         }

         historia.Add( listaIntermediaria );

         //listaIntermediaria.Clear();

      } while (text != null);

      return historia;
   }
```

Exemplo do que acontece para ficar mais claro:
se no meu txt eu tiver:

```
"alguma coisa|outra coisa"
"mais uma coisa|mais outra coisa"
"que coisa|mais coisa"
```

no meu lista final eu terei todas as linhas na primeira posição do list, as duas primeiras linhas na segunda posição, e somente a primeira linha na terceira posição do list, esse foi o resultado que obtive. E tentei adicionar o comando `listaIntermediaria.Clear();`, mas ai o list fica completamente vazio o tempo todo.

Comment: a primeira linha tem dois texto, a segunda linha tem dois textos é isso ??? que você quer como resultado, 3 linhas e cada linha com dois textos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo minimo seria:

```
List<List<string>> lista = new List<List<string>>();
lista.Add("1|2|3".Split("|").ToList());
```

ou seja, no texto encontrada em cada linha eu faria o `split` e no por fim o método `ToList()` para adicionar na `List<List<string>>`.

No seu código utiliza um algo assim:

```
public List<List<string>> carregaHistoria( string nomeHistoria )
{
    List<List<string>> historia = new List<List<string>>();

    FileInfo theSourceFile = 
           new FileInfo ( Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + nomeHistoria + ".txt");

    using (StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText())
    {

        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            historia.Add(line.Split('|').ToList());
        }   

    }

    return historia;

}
```

Comment: eu não entendi exatamente o que acontece, pois quando tentei ajeitar a minha função adicionando o .ToList(), no meu dava um erro falando que .ToList() não era valido, mas então copiei e colei o seu código e funcionou Obrigado!